# I want to group hashtags with the same postId and represent them in an array

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I want to group hashtags with the same postId and represent them in an array

I am currently working on TypeOrm and PostgreSQL

Here is my typeorm code

```
  async findAll(): Promise<Post[]> {
    const posts = this.postRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('posts')
      .select([
        'posts.id',
        'posts.title',
        'posts.createdAt',
        'posts.hits',
        'users.name',
        'hashtags.hashtag',
      ])
      .addSelect((subQuery) => {
        return subQuery
          .select('SUM(likes.postId)')
          .from(PostLike, 'likes')
          .groupBy('likes.postId');
      }, 'likes')
      .leftJoin('posts.user', 'users')
      .leftJoin('posts.hashtags', 'hashtags')
      .leftJoin('posts.postLikes', 'likes')
      // .groupBy('posts.id')
      .getRawMany();
    return posts;
  }
```

Here is my return value

```
[
    {
        "posts_createdAt": "2022-11-15T14:56:54.083Z",
        "posts_id": 41,
        "posts_title": "야호",
        "posts_hits": null,
        "users_name": "chan",
        "hashtags_hashtag": "#야호",
        "likes": null
    },
    {
        "posts_createdAt": "2022-11-15T14:56:54.083Z",
        "posts_id": 41,
        "posts_title": "야호",
        "posts_hits": null,
        "users_name": "chan",
        "hashtags_hashtag": "#여어행",
        "likes": null
    },
    {
        "posts_createdAt": "2022-11-15T14:58:17.661Z",
        "posts_id": 42,
        "posts_title": "여행",
        "posts_hits": null,
        "users_name": "chan",
        "hashtags_hashtag": "#나혼자",
        "likes": null
    },
    {
        "posts_createdAt": "2022-11-15T14:58:17.661Z",
        "posts_id": 42,
        "posts_title": "여행",
        "posts_hits": null,
        "users_name": "chan",
        "hashtags_hashtag": "#제주도",
        "likes": null
    }
]
```

posts table and hashtag table are 'ManyToMany' relationships

post.entity.ts

```
@Entity('posts')
export class Post extends DateContent {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  title: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  content: string;

  //조회 수
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  hits: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.posts)
  user: User;

  @RelationId((post: Post) => post.user)
  userId: number;

  @OneToMany(() => PostComment, (postComment) => postComment.post)
  postComments: PostComment[];

  @OneToMany(() => PostLike, (postLike) => postLike.post)
  postLikes: PostLike[];

  @OneToMany(() => PostImage, (postImage) => postImage.post)
  postImages: PostImage[];

  @ManyToMany(() => Hashtag)
  @JoinTable()
  hashtags: Hashtag[];
}
```

hashtag.entity.ts

```
@Entity('hashtags')
export class Hashtag {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  hashtag: string;
}
```

I look forward to your kind reply.
If you need more information, please let me know in the comments.
Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to add a `.select('ARRAY_AGG(hashtags.hashtag)')` the same way you do for aggregating likes

Comment: This would be so much cleaner and easier using native SQL.

Comment: @yeveloper If you did, I encourage you to [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - otherwise it's unclear whether this problem is solved (answer count is zero in this thread), or how it was solved (paste the new version of your code). See also [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).